# Lazy route component doesn't work if rendered by another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, code-splitting

I've built a toggle component that creates the code chunks for a list of feature components based on the env variable set for the build.

*e.g.:*

```
import React from "react";
import OtherComponent from "./OtherComponent";
import { ToggleFeature, features } from "./ToggleFeature";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <OtherComponent />
      <ToggleFeature feature={features.CustomRoute} suspense={false} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This approach works for almost every component, except for `Route`, it seems to break any routes bellow.

I've thought that the `Suspense` in the middle of the `Switch` was breaking the code, so I've created a boolen prop called suspense to deactivate it inside the `ToggleFeature`, leaving this responsability to the code calling it.

*This works:*

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import RouteCommon from "./RouteCommon";
import { features } from "./ToggleFeature";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/common">Common Route</Link>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/lazy">Lazy Route</Link>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/common" component={RouteCommon} />
            <Route path="/lazy" component={features.CustomRoute} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

*This doesn't work:*

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import RouteCommon from "./RouteCommon";
import { ToggleFeature, features } from "./ToggleFeature";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/common">Common Route</Link>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/lazy">Lazy Route</Link>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/common" component={RouteCommon} />
            <ToggleFeature feature={features.CustomRoute} suspense={false} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is this approach possible for this situation?

Here's a fiddle with the above code running: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-route-kvqp5

Comment: did you tried to lazy the `Switch` component ?, because if you Suspense will wait for the longest script to load as the 'Promise.all` or the parallel in the async library, but if you wrapped all the lazy components inside a parent component it will just wait for the parent component

Comment: It didn't work as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-route-lazy-switch-5pwpy